# Извлечь данные из массива класса

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет. Я с массивами вообще не работал и для меня это темный лес, не могу понять, как можно получить данные из этого класса

```
    static function get_counts( $buckets ) {
    $counts = array();
    $total = 0;
    foreach ( array( 'member', 'guest', 'bot' ) as $user_type ) {
        $count = isset( $buckets[$user_type] ) ? count( @$buckets[$user_type] ) : 0;
        $total += $counts[$user_type] = $count;
    }

    $counts['user'] = $total;

    return $counts;
}
```

Для этого шаблона:

```
UserOnline_Template::get_counts('member');
```

При выводе:

```
print UserOnline_Template::get_counts( 'member' );
```

пишет array, а ошибка - Array to string conversion

Плагин: wp-useronline, с файла template-tags.php
Пару вечеров убил уже, заморочился с этим выводом, так как очень нужно получить количество из этого класса

Comment: "*Пару вечеров убил уже*" - а надо было всего ничего времени потратить на [изучение букваря](http://www.php.su/learnphp/datatypes/?array). Причём желательно до того, как браться за какой-то код вообще.

Comment: да читал я такие "буквари" и все равно не могу разобраться в массиве

Answer (score 1):

Возвращаейте только один элемент массива return $counts['user'], либо в вызывающей программе print(UserOnline_Template::get_counts( 'member' )['user'])

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но выводится только ноль, использовал оба Ваших варианта и менял значения и никак.
По крайней мере из массива хоть что то отобразилось)